How to enter in gui from tty my desktop manager lightdm is deleted and my pc in not connected with internet
How to go to gui from TTY I am trying to install light DM desktop manager but it is not installing because of disconnection from the internet and network manager is not working.
Lightdm is not working so I decided to uninstall it and install that again
I give this command sudo apt remove lightdm
And about the network manager I don't have any idea how it mess up
Right now I give command apt-get light DM then it fetch some website but it is failed because of disconnected through internet and I don't know how to connect the PC from internet in TTY
If someone need more context let me know I can tell from the start
Ubuntu version is 22.04

You have not given any details, you need to add them. How did the DM get deleted? How did network manager get messed up?

Please edit your question and add which version of Ubuntu you are using, along with other information others have asked for.

try this command  sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 and reboot

sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm "lightdm is broken or not fully installed" this error is coming

If you are already logged in at a virtual terminal, you could try bypassing the display manager altogether - just starting a session directly with startx
